# EOF symbolic constant

Tags: c, eof

From *The C Programming Language*:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

"... The solution is that `getchar` returns a distinctive value when there is no more input, a value that cannot be confused with any real character. This value is called `EOF`, for "end of file." We must declare `c` to be a type big enough to hold any value that `getchar` returns. We can't use `char` since `c` must be big enough to hold `EOF` in addition to any possible `char`."

I checked in `stdio.h` and printed the value of EOF on my system, and it's set to `-1`. On my system, `chars` are signed, although I understand that this is system dependent. So, `EOF` can fit in a `char` for my system. I rewrote the small routine above by defining `c` to be a `char` and the program works as intended. There's also a character in the ASCII character table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) that appears to have a blank character corresponding to 255 which appears to act like `EOF`.

So, why does it appear that ASCII has a character (255) designated for EOF? This seems to contradict what is said in the *The C Programming Language* book.

Comment: Because 255 is not the same as -1?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, why does it appear that ASCII has a character (255) designated for EOF?

It hasn't. More precisely, that's not the EOF "character".

The trick is, `getchar()` will always return non-negative values if it has something to read. It will only return `-1` (that's what `EOF` appears to be defined on your implementation) if it encounters end-of-file.

The fact that `char` is:

1. 8 bits wide,
2. signed and
3. uses a 2's complement representation,

is just a quirk of your implementation (although overwhelmingly common nowadays). Thus, if you are using a `char` to store the return value of `getchar()`, then reading the input may terminate prematurely: the character with code 255 will be mistaken for -1 a. k. a. `EOF`, **which is an error.** This is just what happened to you. **It didn't work** -- conversely, your second approach was completely broken.

Comment: Side note: there exists an ASCII character named "EOF" with the value 26 (0x1a), but that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: EOF is system dependent, so I'm sure we'll find other variations.

Comment: @givanse Yes, but `EOF` is *required* to be negative by the standard.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just curious, but after you check that a character is valid, will any problems arise from storing it in a `char` since overflow can occur (if `char` is signed)?

Comment: @jucestain Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior if caused by an arithmetic operator (see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922601/is-char-foo-255-undefined-behavior-if-char-is-signed)), but not when caused by an initialization, so I'd say `char ch = i;` should be fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 It still says the results are implementation defined... Does this mean that the character set should correspond correctly to how the system handles assigning an out-of-range value? Or should I just specify `char` as being `unsigned`?

Comment: @jucestain The results of what? The conversion? It is IB, and you can't really do anything about it. If you want to be absolutely safe, use `unsigned char`.

Comment: The results of `char foo = 255` when `char` is signed as per the question/answer you posted. I.e. its possible for `getchar()` to return the value `255` which I store in a `char`. I think just to be safe I'll use `unsigned char` when using `getchar
()`.

Comment: @jucestain Or just use the common (and correct) idiom and use `int`, and you will then be *completely* safe.

Answer (score 5):

When `getchar()` reads the byte 255, it returns 255. When `getchar()` finds that there is no more input, it returns -1.

If you store the result in a `char`, you cannot distinguish the two. But when you store them in an `int`, you can.  (This statement is independent of the signedness of `char`).

Only if you *know* that the result was valid can you convert it to `char` and get the usual C-style character type.

Answer (score 3):

According to manual on getchar() it always returns int value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
int getchar(void);
...
RETURN VALUE
fgetc(), getc() and getchar() return the character read as 
an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.
```

Thus using char instead of int will cause truncation (int -1 (0xffffffff) becomes char -1 (0xff)) and may cause errors.

Comment: Thanks, my initial problem was I didn't realize `getchar` reads a byte as an `unsigned char` and then casts it to an `int`. Returning `-1' for `EOF` makes sense after realizing this.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how this works imagine what was the guy writing getchar thinking. You need to read a file. Start by creating a routine - for example:

```
unsigned char get_me_a_byte(file)... // 0..255
```

now you want to read all bytes from a file:

```
unsigned char c;

while( c = get_me_a_byte(file) ) // while( (c = get_me_a_byte(file)) != 0 )
{
  ... do sth
}
```

The problem is that it will stop when z zero is encountered but you want to stop once everything is red.
Now you are getting smarter - you know files can be thought of as sequence of bytes. 
What if your **get_me_a_byte** could return 16 or 32 bit type? Then you could use some value that byte cannot hold as end of file marker.

bingo

Since decision is yours you may have:

```
int get_me_a byte_U(file) ... // returning bytes as 0..255
int get_me_a byte_S(file) ... // returning bytes as -128..127
```

Now you can do:

```
int c;
while( (c = get_me_a_byte_U(file) != UUU ) ....
```

where **UUU** could be anything from 256 to MAXINT on your platform

Similarly:

```
int c;
while( (c = get_me_a_byte_S(file) != SSS ) ....
```

where **SSS** could be anything from MININT..-129 and 128..MAXINT

Now if you chose first method there is a question: What should value of UUU (your EOF) be?

(-1) is good for EOF because regardless of what is the bit width of variable you may assign it to it will remain (-1). By 'remain -1' I mean it will always be all ones pattern.

```
char c = -1; // c = 11111111b / 0xFF / 255 (assuming your char is signed 8bit)
short s = -1; // s = 1111111111111111b / 0xFFFF / 65535
int i = -1; // s = 11111111111111111111111111111111b / 0xFFFFFFFF / 4294967295
```

Now it should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction.

- EOF is NOT a character, just a condition found when reading a file.
- ASCII 255 sometimes corresponds to a non-breaking space a.k.a HTML entity `&nbsp;`

As noted in the comments, ASCII encodes only 128 characters, so beyond that you'll find different encodings.

From the table that you linked to I would just say:

> 255 is a non printable character

Comment: ASCII only has 0 .. 127. There are dozens of character sets that use the other byte values in incompatible ways, but none of them is ASCII (and the term "extended ASCII" for any one of them is also misleading).